# Concatenate Split Array from Select Field in LINQ

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I have a list of string elements, each of which can contain a comma separated list of values.  From that, I want to generate a list of all the distinct values in the entire set.

Take the following set of strings for example:

```vb
Dim strings = New List(Of String) From {"A", "B,C,D", "D,E"}
```

I'd like to turn this into:

```vb
{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}
```

Using linq, I could take each element and convert it into a string array.  The following query will just split each string into an array, but it will stay stuffed in it's own array element.

```vb
Dim fieldsLinq = (From s In strings
                  Select s.Split(",")) _
                 .Distinct()
```

I want to concatenate the all of the values into a single array of strings.

I could start by joining all the elements with a comma and THEN splitting the single string, but this feels like the wrong approach.

```vb
Dim fieldsJoin = String.Join(",", strings) _
                       .Split(",") _
                       .Distinct()
```

Are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know VB that well but you could just use SelectMany to flatten the arrays. in C#

```
strings.SelectMany(o=>o.Split(","));
```

Comment: You can do it like this: strings.SelectMany(x => x.Split(',')).Distinct()

Comment: @KyleMit Awesome. Except if you are happy plz

Comment: @Murdock, I'm happy to *accept* and upvote your answer, but as an FYI, you shouldn't feel the need to ask for voting actions from other users, especially within the first hour a question has been asked.

Comment: @KyleMit my apologies

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#) could do the trick:

```vb
Dim fieldsAggregate = strings.Aggregate(New List(Of String), 
                                        Function(seed, s) 
                                            seed.AddRange(s.Split(","))
                                            Return seed
                                        End Function).Distinct()
```

**Update**: Here's the VB version of murdock's answer using [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#) in lambda and query syntax:

```
Dim lambda = strings.SelectMany(Function(s) s.Split(",")) _ 
                    .Distinct()

Dim query = (From outer In strings
             From inner In outer.Split(",")
             Select inner) _
            .Distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not have relevance to the original question, but it may still be useful for a user who came to this page searching for a good way to approach this problem. In my opinion, LINQ is supposed to make developer's life more simple, short and long term.

In this particular case, the alternative approach, i.e. without using LINQ, is very simple already, and much more maintainable. Typically, if you have input data like `"A,B,D"`, you are approaching a maintenance nightmare in the long run, so risking your LINQ query to be extended to a big monster soon.

Consider this code, which does the same thing (old school kicks in):

```
Private Shared Function AggregateSplit(input As List(Of String)) _
                                                             As List(Of String)
  Dim hsItems As New HashSet(Of String)
  For Each s As String In input
    AddRangeToHashSet(hsItems, s.Split(","))
  Next
  Return hsItems.ToList
End Function

Private Shared Sub AddRangeToHashSet(hsItems As HashSet(Of String),
                                     items As IEnumerable(Of String))
  For Each s As String In items
    If hsItems.Contains(s) Then Continue For
    hsItems.Add(s)
  Next
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
Dim r = AggregateSplit(strings)
```

Ideally, you'd have `AddRangeToHashSet` as an extension method already, so you don't need to define it each and every time you need `AddRange` for one. So in this case it is just `AggregateSplit` that you would need to declare. Also much easier to explain what it's doing for a person who is not familiar with LINQ, and you can debug through, if something did not parse well.